# 配列による for文

Tags: c#

```
using System;
class CodeFile1
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] sample = new int[100];
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i = i+1) ;
        sample[i] = i;

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i = i+1)
            Console.WriteLine("This is sample[" +i+ "] : " +sample[i]);
    }
}
```

サンプルアプリを作っています。　上記をコンパイルすると、

```
This is sample[0]:0 This is sample [1]:1 .......
```

にならず、

```
This is sample[0]:0 This is sample [1]:0.......
```

になるのですが、原因がわかりません。ループ文がおかしいんでしょうか？

Comment: 1つめの`for`文は`;`があるため、実際には何もしていません。また、`for`の処理部分はなるべく`{}`で括った方が良いでしょう。

Comment: このようなミスをなくすために`for (i = 0; i < 10; i = i+1)`は`for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`として`int i;`は削除したほうが良いと思いますよ。

Answer (score 4):

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i = i+1) ;
```

セミコロンがあるのでfor文の中身はそこで終了しています。

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i = i+1) {
}
```

と同等と言えばわかりやすいでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

```
        var sample = new int[100];

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            sample[i] = i;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is sample[" + i + "] : " + sample[i]);
        }
```